# Is it possible to set up a reverse DNS record on AWS for address from a different registrar?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-dns

I don't have control over the registrar for the domain we use but the elastic ip and domain have been registered to each other - now I need to set up a mail server on my EC2 instance and therefore be able to set up a reverse DNS record as well. Will I still be able to do this even though aws is not my registering authority?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a technical perspective it doesn't matter where the forward DNS is hosted.

The reverse DNS is typically hosted by the provider of your IP-address, so in your case by Amazon. As long as the forward DNS matches your actual ip-address and the PTR-record you're requesting, Amazon allows you to [set-up a reverse DNS record](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Elastic_IP) by contacting them.

> **Q: Can I configure the reverse DNS record for my Elastic IP address?**
>
> Yes, you can configure the reverse DNS record of your Elastic IP address by [filling out this form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request). Note that a corresponding forward DNS record pointing to that Elastic IP address must exist before we can create the reverse DNS record.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it doesn't matter.

Simply setup your reverse DNS zone on your hosting or on the domain itself using a zone and then a PTR record and then contact them here:

https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

You'll fill in the IP and the host and they will then approve. Ensure it is setup correctly, else they will not approve the reverse DNS.